# How to sample batch from only one class at each iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to train a classifier on one ImageNet dataset (1000 classes each with around 1300 images). For some reason, I need each batch to contain 64 images from the same class, and consecutive batches from different classes. Is it possible (and efficient) with the latest TensorFlow?

`tf.contrib.data.sample_from_datasets` in TF 1.9 allows sampling from a list of `tf.data.Dataset` objects, with `weights` indicating the probabilities. I wonder if the following idea makes sense:

- Save data of each class as a separate tfrecord file.
- Pass a `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` object as the `weights`. The object samples from a Categorical distribution such that each sample looks like `[0,...,0,1,0,...,0]` with 999 `0`s and 1 `1`;
- Create 1000 `tf.data.Dataset` objects, each linked a tfrecord file.

I thought, in this way, maybe at each iteration, `sample_from_datasets` will first sample a sparse weight vector that indicates which `tf.data.Dataset` to sample from, then same from that class.

Is it correct? Are there any other efficient ways?

**Update**

As kindly suggested by P-Gn, one way to sample data from one class would be:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(some_parser_fun)  # parse one datum from tfrecord
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)

if sample_same_class:
    group_fun = tf.contrib.data.group_by_window(
        key_func=lambda data_x, data_y: data_y,
        reduce_func=lambda key, d: d.batch(batch_size),
        window_size=batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.apply(group_fun)
else:
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

dataset = dataset.repeat()
data_batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

A follow-up question can be found at [How to sample batch from a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306461/how-to-sample-batch-from-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your solution could work, if I understand it correctly, because `sample_from_dataset` expects a list of values for its `weights`, not a `Tensor`.

However if you don't mind having 1000 `Dataset`s as in your proposed solution, then I would suggest to simply

- create one `Dataset` per class,
- `batch` each of these datasets — each batch has samples from a single class,
- `zip` all of them into one big `Dataset` of batches,
- `shuffle` this `Dataset` — the shuffling will occur on the batches, not on the samples, so it won't change the fact that batches are single class.

A more sophisticated way is to rely on [`tf.contrib.data.group_by_window`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/group_by_window). Let me illustrate that with a synthetic example.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def gen():
  while True:
    x = np.random.normal()
    label = np.random.randint(10)
    yield x, label

batch_size = 4
batch = (tf.data.Dataset
  .from_generator(gen, (tf.float32, tf.int64), (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([])))
  .apply(tf.contrib.data.group_by_window(
    key_func=lambda x, label: label,
    reduce_func=lambda key, d: d.batch(batch_size),
    window_size=batch_size))
  .make_one_shot_iterator()
  .get_next())

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(batch)
# (array([ 0.04058843,  0.2843775 , -1.8626076 ,  1.1154234 ], dtype=float32),
# array([6, 6, 6, 6], dtype=int64))
sess.run(batch)
# (array([ 1.3600663,  0.5935658, -0.6740045,  1.174328 ], dtype=float32),
# array([3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I can confirm `tf.contrib.data.group_by_window` works on cifar10 dataset so far... I'll do more test to see if it is efficient on ImageNet.

Answer (score -1):

[P-Gn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556659/8270312)
to create separate datasets for each class is probably optimal.
However, this can be avoided as follows

```py
# Init some dataset
num_classes = 10
label = tf.range(num_classes, dtype=tf.int32)
features = tf.cast(label * 10, dtype=tf.float32) + tf.random.uniform(shape=[tf.shape(label)[0]], maxval=0.01)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'label':label, 'features': features})
dataset = dataset.repeat()

# Split to buckets by label
batch_size = 4
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length(
    element_length_func=lambda s: s['label'],
    bucket_boundaries=list(range(1, num_classes)),
    bucket_batch_sizes=[batch_size] * num_classes,
))

# Show result
iterator = dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
for i in range(5):
    print(next(iterator))

# {'label': array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), 'features': array([0.00370963, 0.00370963, 0.00370963, 0.00370963], dtype=float32)}
# {'label': array([1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32), 'features': array([10.009371, 10.009371, 10.009371, 10.009371], dtype=float32)}
# {'label': array([2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32), 'features': array([20.001854, 20.001854, 20.001854, 20.001854], dtype=float32)}
# {'label': array([3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32), 'features': array([30.005934, 30.005934, 30.005934, 30.005934], dtype=float32)}
# {'label': array([4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32), 'features': array([40.001686, 40.001686, 40.001686, 40.001686], dtype=float32)}
```